# Tabs Center Aligned in a WordPress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress

Currently there are no options in the theme to align TABS centered. I tried to play with the CSS in the stylesheet (`style.css`), but with no luck.

how can I make the tabs center aligned?

[image]

```html
/* tab */
.tab-set {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.tab-set ul.tabs-titles {
    padding: 0;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    clear: right;
}
.tab-set .tabs-titles li  {
    padding: 15px 35px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;  
}
.tab-set .tabs-titles li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.tab-set .tabs-titles li.current {
    padding: 15px 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    color: #575a5c;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
.tab-set .tab-content {
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    clear: both;
}
.tab-content p {
    padding: 0;
}
.tab-set.white .tabs-titles li  {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab-set.white .tabs-titles li.current {
    background: #fff;
}
.tab-set.white .tab-content {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to guess the issue since there's no html to make sure the structure is correct.  For sake of cleaner code, I'd do this and update the following:

```
.tab-set ul.tabs-titles {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
}
.tab-set .tabs-titles li {
     padding: 15px 35px;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 800;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-right: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
     display: inline-block;
}
.tab-set .tabs-titles li.current {
     color: #575a5c;
     background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

Try not ever set a fixed height unless needed because that's how items can look all messy.  Have the padding/line-height dictate the height.  I also removed some duplicates.  For example, applying the same padding to .current was just doing the same thing. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Here's my codepen to see it in action: https://codepen.io/thecenteno/pen/LYYgMpv